# QUASAR: Redirection using "push" does not work

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

Good day. I have the following file "pages / Login.vue"
Here the form:
[Simple form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyWP6.png)

```
<template>
<div>
    <q-form @submit="btnlogin">
     <q-input v-model="user" type="text" label="Usuario" />
     <q-input v-model="pass" type="password" label="Contraseña" />
    <q-btn color="primary" label="Ingresar" type="submit"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
import router from 'src/router/index'
export default {
  setup () {
      const $q = useQuasar()

      const user = ref(null)
      const pass = ref(null)
      const btnlogin = async () => {
          axios.post("http://localhost:3050/loginQuest",{
            uss : user.value,
            pww : pass.value
          })
          .then(resp=>{
            if(resp.data=="ERROR"){
              $q.notify({
                type:'negative',
                message:'Datos incorrectos!'
              })
            } 
            else{
              router().push({ path: '/' })
            } 
          })
      }
    return {
        user, pass, btnlogin
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When the verification is successful, the address bar changes to http://localhost: 8080 but the content does not change and the Login.vue form continues to be displayed on the screen.

[it sends me to the path but does not change the content, but if I refresh the page it shows the correct content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSYOW.png)

This is my router/routes.js:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') },
      { path: '/form', component: () => import('pages/Form.vue') },
      { path: '/user', component: () => import('pages/Usuarios.vue') },
      { path: '/prueba', component: () => import('pages/Prueba.vue') },
      { path: '/facturas', component: () => import('pages/Facturas.vue') },
    ],
  },
  { path: '/login', component:()=> import('pages/Login.vue')},
  { path: '/:catchAll(.*)*', component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')}
]

export default routes
```

I changed the quasar.conf.js setting in the "vueRouterMode" section from hash to history. I hope you can help me, I'm stuck in it. Thank you!

Comment: Normally routers cannot be invoked as functions (e.g: `router()`). It should be a router instance, with properties and methods. What are you exporting from `src/router/index`?

Answer (score 3):

Your script should look something like this:

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router' // <- import useRoute here

export default {
  setup () {
      const $q = useQuasar()

      const router = useRouter()

      const user = ref(null)
      const pass = ref(null)
      const btnlogin = async () => {
          axios.post("http://localhost:3050/loginQuest",{
            uss : user.value,
            pww : pass.value
          })
          .then(resp=>{
            if(resp.data=="ERROR"){
              $q.notify({
                type:'negative',
                message:'Datos incorrectos!'
              })
            } 
            else{
              router.push({ path: '/' }) // << router is an object, not a function
            } 
          })
      }
    return {
        user, pass, btnlogin
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `import { useRoute }` or `import { useRouter }` ?

Comment: The good one is `import { useRouter }`  @realtebo

Answer (score 0):

Is Posible that on you are created route on yout router.js or router/index.js  a method for wraper router (if you show you router definition help to know it).
but I was a similar problem, I resolve it with:

```js
let router: Router;
...
 
export default route(function ( ... ) {
    if (router) {
        return router;
    }
    ....
    router = createRouter({
        ... // your code
    });

    return router;
});
```

it require unique intanciated object router. It solve for me.